# Custom sorting method for dhtmlx grid not working

Tags: dhtmlx

Could anyone provide custom sorting method for dhtmlx grid? Mine is not working. Do not know what I am missing.

Answer (score 0):

I use this function to sort ignoring the string case:

```
function str_uncase(a, b, order) {
    return (a.toLowerCase() > b.toLowerCase() ? 1 : -1) * (order === "asc" ? 1 : -1);
}
```

Call it like:

```
grid1.setColSorting("str_uncase,str_uncase,...   ");
```